# How to make Qt Creator 4.5 to show build-in documentation in tool-tip?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have problem with Qt Creator version 4.5. I made fresh installation of QT opensource 5.9.4. When You place the mouse over any Qt function/class it shows a pop-up, but in my case without documentation: [broken tool-tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0qab.png). How to fix it?

P.S. I'm using ClangCodeModel.

EDIT: I wasn't able to fix this issue, but in QtCreator 4.13.3 problem is fixed.

Comment: Why do you think that F1-suggestion pop-up broken? Have you trued to press F1 then?

Comment: F1 works fine, i was talking about documentation in tool-tip not in help page, something like: https://asyoulook.com/images/235802/ff21ba75263e4d04.